# Small caps for the math mode

Tags: math-mode, small-caps

How do I make "E" in this equation a small cap?

```
$x^E$
```

Comment: Hmm, why isn't `$x^E$` just good enough? It typesets `E` in the smaller script style.

Comment: @Andrey: It'll give an "E" in math italic.

Comment: I think it's best to keep questions reserved for the actual questions. Your edit is an answer, so it would be best if you post it as an answer to your own question (and remove your EDIT from the question).

Comment: @Hendrik: normally I'd say it's fine to edit the question with a simple "Thanks, here's what I went with:..." But in this case the poster's final solution is much different from the only posted (and accepted) answer.  So yes, it would be better for @Oldrich to put his solution in his own answer.

Comment: @Andrey Vihrov: E in the `$x^E$` is still far too big and aggressive for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To switch fonts in math mode you often use a command like `\mathit` (for italic) or `\mathrm` (for roman).  But there's no `\mathsc` command.  So just use `\textsc`.

```
$x^{\textsc{e}}$
```

Note that `\textsc{E}` will give a capital **E** that is roughly the same height as the normal shape capital **E**.  In general, if you want a small capital **E**, use `\textsc{e}`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't simply use `$x^{\textsc{e}}$`?

Comment: @Niel: the reason I didn't was that I didn't know you could do that!  For some reason I thought that `\textsc` would require LR mode.  I've edited to reflect your simplification.

Comment: If you want to have _slanted_ small-caps in math mode, you have to fake it: `\mbox{\footnotesize{\textit{E}}}`

Comment: @Jesse, what is the purpose of the `\mbox`?

Comment: @Marian, the `\mbox` ensures some nice spacing around the symbol. Try `${\E}^x$` with and without the `\mbox`, where `\E` is the symbold defined as above. But I'm no expert - more information [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146909/what-does-mbox-do).

Answer (score 20):

The above mentioned `$x^{\textsc{e}}$` works in basic situations, but it has the drawback that the font used will depend on the current text font in the environment. For example, `\texttt{ ... $x^{\textsc{e}}$ ... }` typesets the small capital E in the typewriter font. This is usually undesirable for a mathematical symbol. The problem is most prominent when the surrounding text is bold (such as in a heading): there are no bold extended small caps fonts in the standard Computer Modern font collection, hence the e in `\section{ ... $x^{\textsc{e}}$ ... }` will come out as bold *lower case*. So, if you want a general-purpose macro, it is better to use

```
$x^{\normalfont\textsc{e}}$
```

You can define

```
\newcommand{\mathsc}[1]{{\normalfont\textsc{#1}}}
```

Comment: With `amsmath` a better way would be `\text{\normalfont\scshape#1}` (assuming, by way of contradiction, that the OP really has a problem, which it isn't).

Comment: The poster of the original question most likely does not have a problem any more, given that it is over a year old. However, other people may have problems. Note that this question turns up as the #1 Google hit for “latex math small caps”, so it is worthwhile to document any relevant info here. And yes, I encountered this very problem in a real-world situation, it is not made up.

Comment: Just a side note: If in beamer, `\normalfont\textsc{e}` does not work but `\textrm{\textsc{e}}` does.

Comment: Or maybe ``\textnormal{\textsc{e}}``... See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70632/difference-between-various-methods-for-producing-text-in-math-mode

Answer (score 4):

My chosen solution which works fine is

```
\newcommand{\xE}{\ensuremath{ x^{\mbox{\tiny{E}}} }}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit why chose this solution?