# Lining figures in math mode, but oldstyle figures in URLs

Tags: fontspec, unicode-math, urls, oldstylenums

Basically, I want to achieve the same as for instance in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132607/lining-and-oldstyle-figures-in-maths): Changing the math-mode figures to “old style”. But not in general math, only for URLs, which are set in math mode (in the manual, I read that this is done due to “context-sensitive linebreaking”).

So, a simple MWE:

```
%!TEX program=lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont[]{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}

math: $123$

text: 123

url: \url{123}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The math number should of course stay as they are, but I would prefer to have the same number style in URLs as in normal text. In the MWE, I used the predefined url-style `\urlstyle{same}`. For custom styles, I would use the macro `\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\mathversion{osf}\normalfont}` and define a suitable math version with `\setmathfont[version=osf,....enable oldstyle numbers....]{Libertinus Math}`.
However, I do not know how to “activate” old-style numbers with unicode-math. When adding the option `Numbers={OldStyle}` as for the the main font, I do not observe any effect.

### Edit

I tried it with `\mathversion`s and substitituting only a `range`, but this [does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327944/44467). But `\mathversion`s alone work – at least for equations put inside `$` signs. For URLs, it is somehow ignored.

Update MWE

```
%!TEX program=lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\mathversion{osf}}

\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[version=default]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Serif}[version=osf,Numbers=OldStyle]

\begin{document}

\mathversion{osf}    
math (osf): $123$

\mathversion{default}    
math (default): $123$

text: 123

url: \url{123}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You’d declare the old-style numerals in math mode with `\setmathfont{Libertinus Serif}[range=up/digits, Numbers=OldStyle]` and the math version with `version=osf`. Unfortunately, `range=` and `version=` are mutually exclusive as of 2021.

Comment: A solution might be to `\setmathrm` and use the `\mathrm` font in math mode, but the way `\url` is defined seems to be set up to use commands such as `\rmfamily` or `\ttfamily`, not `\mathrm{123}`.

Comment: @Davislor I found out the same thing (the incompability of ranges/versions), see my edit :/
your second comment probably explains the remaining effect of url not showing OSFs.

Comment: The URL implementation of `hyperref` might work better for you?

Comment: @Davislor Oh, I thought, `hyperref` uses the `url` package? I do use `hyperref` indeed, and wanted to change the appearance of links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

url uses math mode, but the font is the text font. I'm using tex gyre heros below to make the difference more obvious.

The problem is that math mode in lualatex requires fonts that use the basic renderer, but text fonts typically want the node or harf mode. You can try to force the basic mode for the url's, but it can mean that you loose text options which work only with node mode. A real solution would require a reimplementation of url which doesn't use math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlFont{\addfontfeature{Renderer=Basic}}

\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle}]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathfont[]{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}

math: $123$

text: 123

url: \url{123}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do exactly what I looked for! Are there any noticable effects of 'loosing text options'? (worst case maybe loosing some characters?)

Comment: no you won't loose chars, but some open type features won't work, like e.g. stylistic sets. see a longish discussion here https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/204

Comment: OK, thanks, I think I can live with this for now (URLs in the reference list).