# Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode

Tags: math-mode, comparison, text-mode, roman

What is the difference between `\text`, `\textrm`, `\textnormal`, and `\mbox` (and possibly other commands commonly used to produce text in math mode)?

Various (La)TeX tutorials teach different methods, and I am sure that there is either a best one or there are subtly different usage scenarios.

Comment: Also see [Is there a preference of when to use \text and \mathrm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/is-there-a-preference-of-when-to-use-text-and-mathrm)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Update:** Example added without `amstext` to show the effect of this package on the other `\text...` commands.

Example file without package `amstext` (or `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  $\csname #1\endcsname{#1}^{\csname #1\endcsname{#1}}$%
}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\sffamily\bfseries\itshape Text mode: sans serif, bold, italics.

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \test{mbox}\\
  \test{textrm}\\
  \test{textnormal}\\
  \test{mathrm}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Differences without amstext]

Example file with package `amstext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tgpagella}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  $\csname #1\endcsname{#1}^{\csname #1\endcsname{#1}}$%
}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\sffamily\bfseries\itshape Text mode: sans serif, bold, italics.

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \test{mbox}\\
  \test{text}\\
  \test{textrm}\\
  \test{textnormal}\\
  \test{mathrm}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
$ \textnormal{[a b c \"a \ss] becomes }
  \mathrm{[a b c \"a \ss]}
  \textnormal{ in mathrm}
$

\end{document}
```

> [image: Differences with amstext]

- `\mbox` uses the current text font. The size is constant and does not change in subscripts, superscripts, fractions, …
- `\text` of package `amstext` (or `amsmath`) uses the current text font, but adapt the size according to the current math style. Therefore it needs `\mathchoice` that has an efficiency impact that the text is set four times for all math styles and later, when TeX knows the math style, it chooses the right version.
- `\textrm` uses the text roman font, but the other font parameters like encoding, shape and series are taken from the current text font. Font size is only adapted to the current math style if package `amstext` (or `amsmath`) is loaded.
- `\textnormal` uses `\normalfont`, the size is only adapted to the currrent math style if package `amstext` (or `amsmath`) is loaded.
- `\mathrm` uses the math roman font that might differ from the text roman font. Also the spacing is done according to math and the encoding differs from the text encoding.

For text in math I would load package `amstext` (or `amsmath`) and use `\text` or `\textnormal`. `\text` is shorter to type, but the dependency on the current text font might be sometimes an advantage, sometimes a disadvantage. For subscripts I would prefer `\textnormal`:

```
v_{\textnormal{car}} \ge v_{\textnormal{bicycle}}
```

But additional text might be better set in the current text font:

```
a \stackrel{\text{according to \dots}}{=} \frac{b}{c} \quad \text{for $c \ne 0$}
```

Comment: In my `\text` can be noticeably slower than `\hbox`/`\mbox`. Is this so? Of course, when proper scaling is needed, choosing `\text` might simply be necessary.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Yes, thanks, there is an efficiency impact, because `\text` needs the service of `\mathchoice` to get the right math style. I have updated the answer.

Comment: You wrote that `\textrm` and `\textnormal` will produce correctly sized text in math mode if `amstext` or `amsmath` is loaded. Which other font commands (`\textit`, `\textsf`, `\texttt`, `\emph`, ...) will have been size-corrected as well?

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Package `amstext` contains `\let\nfss@text\text`. Thus all commands that use `\nfss@text` work with correctly sized text in math, e.g. all commands defined via `\DeclareTextFontCommand`.

Comment: And in `latex.ltx` the following commands are defined using `\DeclareTextFontCommand`: `\textrm`, `\textsf`, `\texttt`, `\textnormal`, `\textbf`, `\textmd`, `\textit`, `\textsl`, `\textsc`, `\textup`, `\emph`

Comment: Which permit line breaking? Obviously `\mbox` does not. I think `\text` does and that's a reason to prefer it for me. (In inline maths mode, obviously.)

Comment: @cfr None does support line breaking in math mode. Either the text ends up in text mode (`\mbox` or `\nfss@text`, both are using the unbreakable `\hbox`) or the material goes into a unbreakable math subformula (`\mathrm`).

Answer (score 19):

I personally consider Herbert Voss' [`mathmode`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode) document one of the definitive guides to `mathmode`.

He covers the differences in Section 9, pg. 27

[image]

If you've installed TeX Live, you can access it on your machine using `texdoc mathmode`, in MiKTeX you will get it with `texdoc voss-mathmode`.

Comment: Actually `\textrm` *doesn't* force upright shape, it only sets the "roman family" attribute and leaves the others as they were (using those holding outside the formula, if it appears in math mode). So `\textit{abc $\textrm{def}$}` will print "def" in italics.

Comment: Please also consider section 37.1 where he also considers amsmath's `\text`: "The \text macro can be used at any place [..]" Or just read his answer to this very question :-)

Comment: Is this still up to date? The texdocs give me a different pdfs that are not the mathmode document.

Comment: @Blubber perhaps not, feel free to edit as you see fit. This answer is nearly 9 years old at time of writing. Do always feel free to make things better :)

Answer (score 9):

without using any package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$Math - \mathrm{upright} - \textrm{upright} - \mbox{upright}$  \par\Large
$A^{\mathrm{text}}_{\mathrm{text}}$ \quad $A^{\textrm{text}}_{\textrm{text}}$\quad
$A^{\mbox{text}}_{\mbox{text}}$     \quad $A^{\textnormal{text}}_{\textnormal{text}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, for text one should use `amsmath` and the `\text` command which uses the correct font size