# \mathrm{} or \mbox{}? What is the convention when writing a equation?

Tags: fonts, equations

When writing a equation, sometimes we need write letters non-italic.
For example, let `A` be a matrix and its transpose should be `A^{\mathrm{T}}` instead of `A^T`.
In addition, if a letter does not represent a variable, it should not be italic either.

**My question is**: there are several ways such as `\mathrm{}` and `\mbox{}`. They will give slightly different results. Let's take the transpose of a matrix for example. Which one should we use? `A^{\mbox{T}}` or `A^{\mathrm{T}}`? What is the convention when writing technique papers?

Comment: Not to forget `\text{}`... :)

Comment: related [Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70632)

Comment: @cmhughes: thanks. But I'm actually more interested in which one should be used in technique papers. Up to now, I believe people can use what ever they want as long as the formation is reasonable:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all you should use the `amsmath` package, that makes commands such as `\textrm` to respect the sizes for subscripts and superscripts.

What's the difference between `\mathrm` and `\textrm`? The former chooses a *math alphabet*, that is a fixed combination of font attributes, typically

- Encoding: OT1
- Family: default Roman family (`\rmdefault`)
- Weight: medium
- Shape: normal

The latter (`\textrm`) builds a box in which `\rmfamily` is issued but, like every `\text...` command, all other font attributes are unchanged with respect to the font which is current outside the formula. So, with the following input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
A test $a^\textrm{test}$

\itshape A test $a^\textrm{test}$
\end{document}
```

the first "test" will be upright and the second one will be in italics. In a boldface context, the bold series attribute will not change.

The command `\text` will simply choose the font which is current outside the formula.

Another difference is that `\math...` commands ignore spaces in their argument, while `\text...` commands don't.

If your problem is to insert letters which don't represent mathematical variables, usually as subscript, say "efficient force" **F**<sub>eff</sub>, you should use `\textnormal` or `\mathrm` (the latter has limitations about what characters one can use, to wit, only unadorned Latin letters):

```
\mathbf{F}_\textnormal{eff}
```

So, for your transpose operator, you can use `\mathrm{T}`, probably hidden in a personal command:

```
\newcommand{\transp}{\mathrm{T}}
```

and `$A^\transp$` for "the transpose of A". For more complicated input, `\textnormal` will be the better choice.

To the contrary, for *textual* insertion in formulas such as

```
\[
a = b \quad\text{if and only if}\quad b = a
\]
```

you *should* use `\text`, so that this will inherit the surrounding font attributes.

Answer (score 10):

use *always* the macro `\text{..}` from package `amsmath`. It takes the surrounding text size into account and uses the text font. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\huge
$x^{\mathrm{ffa}}x^{\mbox{ffa}}x^{\text{ffa}}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But under what circumstance should we use `\mathrm{xxx}`? It seems `\mathrm{xxx}` also gives reasonable results. In addition, if the font size is a problem for `\mbox`, we may use `\scriptsize` to solve it. Anyway, I am wondering which one do people use in technique papers. Or people just use whatever they want? Thanks.

Comment: `\mathrm` uses the math font in upright mode and should be used for operators when not defined with `\mathop`. For text like characters I use _always_ `\text`

Comment: `\text` will use the font which is current outside the formula.

Comment: I'd say the `T` here is more of an operator, just not placed in the conventional place as other operators, and therefore should be set in `\mathrm`. `\text` is for labels that do not have inherent mathematical meaning.

Comment: Also `\text{}` allows space. $A^{\text{power two}}\neq A^{\mathrm{power one}}$.