# In "math-mode line" non-math type

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I'd like to type non-math text inside of the bracket math text lines, or know of a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

In the following, I don't literally type \nomath.  I don't know what I need to type there in order to make this work.

**This is what I type** (the dashes are disappearing, I don't know why):

```
\begin{document}

\[ K=L \]

\[ A = B \nomath or \nomath A_1 = B_1\]

\end{document}
```

**This is what I get:**

> K=L
>
> A=B
>
> or
>
> A_1=B_1

**This is what I want:**

> K=L
>
> A=B or A_1=B_1

What I'd like for the or word to be in non-math text mode, with everything around it following the normal rules according to the dashes and brackets.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thanks for editing the post so it looks nicer, and where I can find more posting tips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the `amsmath` package, you should be able to write something like

```
\[A = B \text{ or } A_1 = B_1\]
```

You'll have to manually add space around the `or`.  You can do it as I did or you can do it as:

```
\[A = B \quad \text{or} \quad A_1 = B_1\]
```

**EDIT 1**

Here's a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\[A = B \text{ or } A_1 = B_1\]

\[A = B \quad \text{or} \quad A_1 = B_1\]

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2**

A comparison of `\mbox{...}` vs `\text{...}`

```
\[ A_{\mbox{Hi}} \text{ vs } A_{\text{Hi}}\]
```

If you want to know more about the differences between these, you should probably post another question.

Or see [Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70632/difference-between-various-methods-for-producing-text-in-math-mode)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Although I couldn't get any of your suggestions to work, you gave me the terminology I needed to find what I could get to work, which was using "\mbox{ or }".

Comment: Did you use `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble to your document?

Comment: Maybe?  I guess the preamble isn't the part before the \documentclass{article}, but after.  When I put \usepackage{amsmath} before \documentclass{article}, \text{or} doesn't work as I desired.  After, and it does.  On a related note, is there any effective difference between \mbox{or} and \text{or}?

Comment: Usually, the `\documentclass{...}` declaration should come at the beginning of the document.  There are exceptions to this.  But if you are new to LaTeX, that might be a good rule of thumb to initially follow.  Yes, there is a difference between `\mbox{or}` and `\text{or}`.  In brief, `\text{...}` is sensitive to its context and chooses the correct font size.  See 2nd edit above.