# How can I make text appear correctly in an equation?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

The basic outline of the equation below is correct but how can I make the text appear correctly right now it appears scrunched up?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \left.
 k_S

= \left\lbrace
\begin{array}{l}
k_{LW}    \text{if} k_{ICOMP}<k_{LW} \\
k_{ICOMP} \text {otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You didn't include the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), as it is needed for your use of `align*`. Moreover, you don't need `align` for this equation, since an `equation*` environment would do just as well. Finally, your construction is also made simple using the `cases` environment (also supplied by `amsmath`).

Comment: ...also see [In “math-mode line” non-math type](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104453/5764).

Comment: using \text{} doesn't work?

Comment: Okay, then you need to provide more information as to "why" it doesn't work. Just saying that doesn't help.

Comment: see the edit above I tried doing it with the \text{} but the text still looks terrible

Comment: You're not including the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) as part of your preamble (`\usepackage{amsmath}`), which probably will fix what you call "terrible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? Note I made the subscripts upright, since they seemed to be acronyms of some sort, rather than indices or variable names.  I also adjusted `\arraycolsep` from its default, to tune the gap between the left brace and the following content.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 k_S
= \left\{
\arraycolsep=1pt\relax
\begin{array}{l}
\text{$k_\text{LW}$    if $k_\text{ICOMP}<k_\text{LW}$} \\
\text{$k_\text{ICOMP}$ otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why no use `cases` of the [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) package?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  k_S=\begin{cases}
k_{\text{LW}} & \text{if } k_{\text{ICOMP}}<k_{\text{LW}} \\
k_{\text{ICOMP}} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or `cases*` from  `mathtools`: the 2nd column will then be in text mode.