# Differentiating between \hbox and \mbox

Tags: boxes

What are the differences between `\hbox` and `\mbox`?

Related:

- This [answer to "What are the different kinds of boxes in (La)TeX?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83936/14996) discusses different boxes in general.
- This [answer to "Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70641/14996) differentiates `\text` from `\mbox`.

Comment: The main difference is that using `\hbox` in LaTeX can lead to unexpected results. So always use the latter, unless you know what you're doing with `\hbox`.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`\hbox` is a TeX primitive and `\mbox` is a LaTeX macro defined via

```
\long\def\mbox#1{\leavevmode\hbox{#1}}
```

The `\leavevmode` means that it starts a paragraph, compare:

```
\hbox{one}
\hbox{two}
three
```

with

```
\mbox{one}
\mbox{two}
three
```

The other difference is that the argument is parsed as a normal macro argument, so for example `\mbox a` works and is identical to `\mbox{a}` whereas `\hbox a` is a syntax error. `\mbox{\verb|{|}` will lead to errors but `\hbox{\verb|{|}` will box a verbatim `{`.

If you do use a brace group for the argument it has to be explicit `{}` (or other characters with catcodes 1 and 2) but `\hbox` can use implicit braces such as `\hbox\bgroup` ... `\egroup` (in particular you can start a box in one macro and end it in another).

Don't use `\hbox` in a LaTeX document (although you will often see it in internal package code).

---

As requested, some further details on `\leavevmode`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

compare

\hbox{one}
\hbox{two}
three

with

\mbox{one}
\mbox{two}
three

see?


compare

zero
\hbox{one}
\hbox{two}
three

with

zero
\mbox{one}
\mbox{two}
three

see?

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the first `compare` is a paragraph break, so TeX goes into *vertical* mode. In vertical mode, boxes are stacked vertically.  The next two boxes are `\hbox`es with `one` and `two` so they are appended vertically to the current vertical list. Then comes the letter `t` of `three`; letters are not allowed in vertical mode so TeX pushes it back into the input and instead starts a new paragraph, adds the paragraph indentation and then sees the `three` again in horizontal mode.

After the first `with` there is again a paragraph break, but this time TeX sees `\leavevmode` (or more exactly the `\unhbox` in its definition), so it starts a new paragraph, adds the indentation and *then* sees `\hbox{one}` in horizontal mode. `\leavevmode` does nothing in h-mode so after the glue from the word space resulting from the end-of-line character, TeX sees `\hbox{two}`, which comes *horizontally* after `one`, and `three` follows in the same paragraph.

After the second `compare`, TeX is again in vertical mode, but this time the paragraph is started by `zero`, so TeX is already in horizontal mode before it sees the `\hbox`, so `\hbox` and `\mbox` act the same way.

Basically LaTeX goes to some lengths to *never* expose the primitive TeX box behaviour: all LaTeX boxes start with `\leavevmode` so that they act like `\mbox` and not `\hbox`.
(The difference is basically the same as the difference between `\parbox` (LaTeX) and `\vbox` (TeX) and `\rule` (LaTeX) and `\hrule` (TeX) for example.)