# Unwanted line break after framed text at the beginning of a line in ConTeXt

Tags: context

I am trying to use the ConTeXt command `\inframed` to add a border to arbitrary text within a line/paragraph. MWE to show problem:

```
\starttext
a \inframed{b} c
\blank
\inframed{d} e
\stoptext
```

Expected output: "d" and "e" appear on same line, as with "a", "b", and "c".

Actual output: line break after "d".

[image: Sample output]

Is this supposed to happen, and in either case, what can be done to prevent it? The ConTeXt Wiki pages on the "(in)framed" command and a Google search yielded no leads.

Comment: You can use `\dontleavehmode\inframed{d} e`: See http://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg30719.html

Comment: I think using ``\mbox{\inframed{d} e}`` might solve your problem as well, except I'm not super familiar with ConTeXt.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour has nothing to do with ConTeXt actually, but a is a consequence of the fact that a box cannot start a paragraph.  There are several possibilities to force a paragraph.  Some suggestions are also given [in the Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Unexpected_behavior#Unsolicited_Vertical_Mode).

1. Don’t start the paragraph with a box.

   ```
   \starttext
   a \inframed{b} c
   \stoptext
   ```

   [image]
2. Force TeX to switch to horizontal mode.  This can be done by either `\dontleavehmode` or `\leavevmode`.  Recommended is `\dontleavehmode` because it does not check for vmode before doing the switch and has therefore slightly better performance.

   ```
   \starttext
   \dontleavehmode\inframed{b} c
   \stoptext
   ```

   [image]
3. Explicitly place the indentation box.

   ```
   \starttext
   \indent\inframed{b} c
   \stoptext
   ```

   [image]

I’m sure there are more methods but these are the ones which came to my mind immediately.

---

After reading your comment I thought that you be interested in this:

```
\definetextbackground
  [framedsnippet]
  [
    background=,
    framecolor=black,
    location=text,
  ]

\starttext

Hello World!
\starttextbackground[framedsnippet]
This is a very long sentence spanning several lines to show off that
\type{textbackground} can span accross lines.
\stoptextbackground\ % <- We need this to avoid skipping spaces
Goodbye World!

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Okay. Really, what I want is to be able to use the same command anywhere within a paragraph to add a border to a short string of text. (Will update the question.) So would custom command with \inframed preceded by \dontleavehmode as in #2 always work?

Comment: Also, I wonder if it might be good to include @MarcoDaniel's reference, or at least mention "vertical mode" explicitly, because this completely unobvious to those (like me) who don't know plain TeX.

Comment: @KennethHanson As for a reference, this has already been discussed on TeX.SX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode/22853#22853 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118164/differentiating-between-hbox-and-mbox/118169#118169

Comment: Thanks. This `\definetextbackground` doesn't appear in the manual and is hardly mentioned anywhere, but looks promising.

Comment: @KennethHanson http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TextBackground