# What is the use of the \hbox in a \newcommand command?

Tags: boxes

In page 90 of Grätzer's *More Math into LaTeX* (5th edition), he uses a \newcommand command to define a binary mathematical operation as follows:

```
\newcommand{\circwithdot}{\mathbin{\rlap{$\mspace{2mu}\cdot$}\hbox{$\circ$}}}
```

What is the use of the \hbox here? Why does not he use the \mbox command? Are they the same in this case?

Comment: Related: [Differentiating between \hbox and \mbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118164/2693).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: »Why does not he use the `\mbox` command?«  Because the author made a mistake here.  In LaTeX `\mbox` should be preferred over `\hbox`, see the linked threads above.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: While the link is about the differences between `\hbox` and `\mbox`, it doesn't really answer the question.