# How to use xcolor to color column text, but don't change spacing between rows?

Tags: tables, spacing, color

I have an example of some code that colors a column, and I show here that the uncolored column has less spacing between rows.  How do I color my column text without changing the spacing between rows?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\color{red}}p{2cm}>{\color{red}}p{2cm}}
one & two \\
three & four \\
five & six\\
seven & eight \\
nine & ten
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
one & two \\
three & four \\
five & six\\
seven & eight \\
nine & ten
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One solution is to just use `\textcolor{mytext}` rather than `{\color{}mytext}` in the actual table, but quite laborious to put that around each entry.

Comment: If you need the complete table text should be in red, you can try `{\color{red} \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\leavevmode`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\leavevmode\color{red}}p{2cm}>{\leavevmode\color{red}}p{2cm}}
one & two \\
three & four \\
five & six\\
seven & eight \\
nine & ten
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
one & two \\
three & four \\
five & six\\
seven & eight \\
nine & ten
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works OK with the `l` column type, so we can define a new column type, `M{}`, which puts a `minipage` in a column of type `l`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\begin{minipage}{#1}\arraybackslash}l<{\end{minipage}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\color{red}}M{2cm}>{\color{red}}M{2cm}}
  one & two \\
  three & four \\
  five & six\\
  seven & eight \\
  nine & ten
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{>{\color{blue}}M{20mm}>{\color{green}}M{20mm}}
  one & two \\
  three & four \\
  five & six\\
  seven & eight \\
  nine & ten
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
  one & two \\
  three & four \\
  five & six\\
  seven & eight \\
  nine & ten
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: coloured tabular columns without space]

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if we replace `parbox` with `mbox`.  You can read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118169/48478) to understand the difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{>{\color{red} } m{2cm} > {\color{blue} } m{2cm} }
        one & two \\
        three & four \\
        five & six\\
        seven & eight \\
        nine & ten
    \end{tabular}   
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{2cm}}
        one & two \\
        three & four \\
        five & six\\
        seven & eight \\
        nine & ten
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

As I have mentioned in the comment, if you need the complete table text to be in a single color, you can just wrap tabular with `\color{red} \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} }` or `\textcolor{red}{ \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} }`.

```
\textcolor{red}{
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{2cm}}
        \hline 
        one & two \\
        \hline 
        three & four \\
        five & six\\
        seven & eight \\
        nine & ten
    \end{tabular}   }
```

### Caution:

This approach make the complete tabular to be  red in colour including the `\hline`s.

[image]