# Minus sign not aligning with fraction

Tags: alignment, superscripts, fractions

When I use subscripts and superscript with `\frac` the numerator and denominator looks very tight,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]
\[e^{-\dfrac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I tried using `\dfrac` but not the minus sign and fraction line are not aligned.

[image]

Anybody has a smart fix to this?

Comment: please always provide a complete test file so people can see the issue and test answers. `\dfrac` in a superscript is probably excessive, you could set the whole superscript, including the - in `\displaystyle` rather than the default `\scriptstyle` or use `\exp` notion rather than `e^{..}` so the expression is not in a superscript

Comment: My preference would be to move the minus sign to the numerator: \frac{-(...)}{...}

Answer (score 24):

The cause of the misalignment is that the minus sign is in `scriptstyle`, but the fraction is being forced into `displaystyle`. Here are a few options:

`\[e^{\displaystyle -\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]`

[image]

`\[e^{\dfrac{-(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]`

[image]

`\[e^{-(x-\mu_2)^2/2\sigma^2_2}\]`

[image]

`\[\exp\bigl(-(x-\mu_2)^2/2\sigma^2_2\bigr)\]`

[image]

Comment: Note that it's unclear whether the vertical alignment is correct in the last example, because the minus sign is altogether missing.

Comment: @BenVoigt, there is no issue with the alignment in the last expression since there is a common baseline and only one style. But I added the missing minus sign.

Answer (score 19):

Let's consider five separate typographic approaches to displaying the expression at hand:

- `e^{-\dfrac{(...)}{...}}` and `e^{\dfrac{-(...)}{...}}`
- `e^{-\tfrac{(...)}{...}}` and `e^{\tfrac{-(...)}{...}}`
- `e^{-(x-\mu_2)^2/(2\sigma_2^2)}` (inline-style fraction in exponent)
- `\exp(-\dfrac{...}{...})` and `\exp(-\tfrac{...}{...})`
- `\exp\bigl(-(x-\mu_2)^2/(2\sigma_2^2)\bigr)` (inline-style fraction)

[image]

I think we may posit that the expressions in the first two rows look *awful*. (Ok, row 1 is truly awful, whereas row 2 is just plain awful.) If you *must* use `e^{...}` notation, then do please consider using the inline-fraction variant in row 3. That said, I'd really, really recommend that you consider adopting `\exp(...)` notation; cf. rows 4 and 5.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
e^{-\dfrac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}} \qquad
e^{\dfrac{-(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}} \\[\jot]
e^{-\tfrac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}} \qquad
e^{\tfrac{-(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}} \\[\jot]
e^{-(x-\mu_2)^2/(2\sigma_2^2)}        \\[\jot]
\exp\biggl(-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\biggr) \qquad
\exp\Bigl(-\tfrac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\Bigr) \\[\jot]
\exp\bigl(-(x-\mu_2)^2/(2\sigma_2^2)\bigr)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want necessarily to use `\dfrac` with the minus sign you add `\ooalign`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]
\[e^{\ooalign{$-$}\dfrac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: Using the comment of `@campa` with `\hbox` you obtain the same result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]
\[e^{\hbox{$-$}\dfrac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update 2022-04-14

Based on the discussions from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118164), I propose to **use `\mbox` instead of `\hbox`**.

> The main difference is that using `\hbox` in LaTeX can lead to
> unexpected results. So always use the latter, unless you know what
> you're doing with `\hbox`.
> *-- egreg*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
default: \[e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]
hbox: \[e^{\hbox{$-$}\dfrac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]
mbox: \[e^{\mbox{$-$}\dfrac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hope I don't sound too blunt, but `\ooalign` isn't doing anything useful here. A simple `\hbox` would do.

Comment: @campa No, don't worry. I have only seen that it worked and I have used `\ooalign` :-(

Comment: @campa and Sebastiano Please see my edit. I hope that you are ok with it.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You're always welcome......all the end of my life.