# how do I get a hyphen in \mathrm

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

A simple question I think, but if I write `$\omega{\mathrm{anti-Stokes}}$`, the hyphen looks an awful lot like a minus sign. If I naively try `$\omega{\mathrm{anti\hyp{}Stokes}}$` (I think `\hyp{}` requires `\usepackage{hyphenat}`) I get the same result - I'm not actually surprised, presumably it sets the same character.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\omega_{\mathrm{anti-Stokes}}$
anti-Stokes
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The minus sign looks like a rather thin en-dash instead of a hyphen.

Comment: It doesn't look like a minus sign, it is one. Use `\textrm` (and the  amsmath package so it gets smaller in subscripts)

Comment: Related: [Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70632/16967)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you - for the record (I'm sure you know this) mathtools does the job just as well as amsmath (can't remember why I switched from amsmath to mathtools, but that's another story.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, that's a good question with some interesting material in the answers - almost required reading I think.  Now I know the "why" behind my question - htanks.

Comment: @ChrisH `mathtools` loads `amsmath` and fixes some bugs

Comment: @AndrewSwann, OK, I thought it was a sort of replacement with bugfixes, I didn't know the mechanism, and therefore didn't know whether it replaced everything - thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is to summarise the answers in the comments, and avoid leaving the question unanswered.

As discussed in more detail in the answers to [Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70632/28808), there are several ways to produce upright letters in maths mode.  [Heiko Oberdiek's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70641/28808) is particularly worth a read for the curious or confused.

Relevant here is that `\mathrm` is meant for setting upright characters in maths mode, and therefore uses the maths roman font, spacing and encoding. On the other hand `\textrm` uses the text roman font and the font parameters of the current text mode font, i.e. `-` will be encoded as a hyphen rather than a minus sign when using `\textrm`.  Because `\textrm` inherits its parameters from the surrounding text, it doesn't guarantee an upright shape: for example in a `theorem` environment it will inherit italic shape.  `\textnormal` uses `\normalfont`, only the size then changes

`\textrm` and `\textnormal`, in the absence of the *amsmath* package do not scale in subscripts, so *amsmath* must be loaded in cases like this, either directly or by another package such as *mathtools* which fixes some bugs in *amsmath*.

Comment: `\textrm` does not guarantee upshape: in a theorem statement you'd get your subscript in italics. Use `\textnormal` which does the right thing.

Comment: thanks @egreg, I've edited that in. But if I understand correctly (and it's more than possible that I don't) `\textnormal` doesn't guarantee anything much - in particular after `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` for example, wouldn't  `\textnormal` give you sans serif, regardless of the maths font used?

Comment: In the case of all sans serif, textual sub/superscripts should be sans serif as well.

Comment: @egreg, I would say only if maths is sans serif, but this isn't the issue I thought it was given that I'd forgotten that beamer (the only time I use sans serif and LaTeX) uses sans serif for maths.