# font size in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

```
$\sum\limits_{\substack{locations \\ L_j}}$
```

The word *locations* is quite long - longer than the summation symbol Sigma.

I would like to control the size of *only* the word *locations*, but I am having trouble

1. `$\sum\limits_{\substack{ locations \\ L_j}}$` has no effect on the size of *locations*.
2. `\fontsize{0.5cm}{1pt}\selectfont $\sum\limits_{\substack{locations \\ L_j}}$` makes the summation symbol sigma smaller but not *locations
3. inserting `\tiny`, `\scriptsize` etc has no discernable affect.  Nor does `\text{\tiny locations}`, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `\text{\tiny{locations}}` does make it a bit smaller. To make it really small, you could try `\scalebox`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document} 
$\sum\limits_{\substack{\scalebox{0.5}{locations} \\ L_j}}$

$\sum\limits_{\substack{\text{\tiny{locations}} \\ L_j}}$

$\sum\limits_{\substack{\text{locations} \\ L_j}}$
\end{document}
```

[image: locations 2]

Another option would be to use `\mathclap` from the [mathtools package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) to horizontally smash `locations`. This allows the summand to appear on top of locations (so you don't get a big space after the sum.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\sum\limits_{\substack{\mathclap{\text{locations}} \\ L_j}}$ A
\end{document}
```

[image: locations 1]

However, I think the best option would be to define some notation to avoid this construction.

> Let $\Lambda$ represent the set of all locations...

Comment: looks better! although i do prefer your "`Let $\Lambda$ ...`" formulation, i think the others would look better with just a tiny bit of extra space between the two lines.  maybe `\\[.2ex]`; a `\mathstrut` is probably too much, but the lack of descenders on `locations` is allowing too much "compaction".

Comment: As a mathematician, I am totally on board with the notation-solution.  But when you give a presentation *to a non-mathematics audience*, you try to be as light on notation as possible - using English words rather than letters.  Hence my problem here.  Thank you, though, it is a good point.

Answer (score 5):

Good morning,

I suggest :

```
\sum\limits_{\substack{ {\scriptscriptstyle \text{locations}} \\ L_j}}{y}
```

In a more general manner, in math mode you can use
\displaystyle ; \textstyle ; \scriptstyle and \scriptscriptstyle to control font size.

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Changing_font_size for detailed article.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\mbox`:

```
$\sum\limits_{\substack{\mbox{\tiny {\emph{locations}}}\\ L_j}}$
```

Remove `\emph` if you do now want the text to be slanted.

Comment: What is the difference between `\mbox{}` and `\text{}`? The OP had tried the second one.

Comment: `\mbox` uses the current text font. The size is constant and does not change in subscripts, superscripts, fractions,etc.

`\text` of package amstext (or amsmath) uses the current text font, but adapt the size according to the current math style. Therefore it needs `\mathchoice` that has an efficiency impact that the text is set four times for all math styles and later, when TeX knows the math style, it chooses the right version.

For more boxes see for example [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70632/difference-between-various-methods-for-producing-text-in-math-mode)

Answer (score 2):

One easy way I found to make math font smaller is to wrap a "_{ }" around your math/text - effectively making it a subscript of an invisible character.

In your case:

```
$\sum\limits_{ \substack{  _{locations} \\ L_j} }$
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining a new `\math...`-type command using `unicode-math` package's `\setmathfontface` command to set a scaled-down text-in-maths font could be an option.

[image: locations]

For "text fonts that are set up to behave correctly in mathematics, and should be used for multi-letter identifiers" (`texdoc unicode-math`, s3.1)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfontface\mathfsmall{Latin Modern Sans}[Scale=0.6,Colour=blue]


\begin{document}

$\sum\limits_{\substack{\mathfsmall{locations\makebox[0pt]{\phantom{$\mathfsmall{p}$}}} \\ L_j}}$ % p supplies descender for \\

\end{document}
```