# Should \mathrm work in \gather* environment?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I am trying to use `\mathrm` in `gather*` environment, but the result is text without any spaces. How can I correct that, please?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{gather*}
  P(A) = P(B) + P(C) \qquad \mathrm{4-momentum conservation}\\
  P(A) = \left( m_{A}, \vec{0} \right) \qquad \mathrm{in the rest frame of A}\\
  \Downarrow\\
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathrm` still sets content in *math*. You're looking for `\text` or perhaps `\textrm` or `\mbox`.

Comment: Not only do you get no space `-` is set as a minus sign, not as a hyphen.

Comment: note this is unrelated to gather, you see the same in `$\mathrm{a b c}$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\mathrm` does work in `gather*` and the output is as expected: it provides a *math* related roman (upright) font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  P(A) = P(B) + P(C) \qquad \mathrm{4-momentum conservation} \\
  P(A) = P(B) + P(C) \qquad \textrm{4-momentum conservation} \\
  P(A) = \bigl( m_{A}, \vec{0}\, \bigr) \qquad \text{in the rest frame of $A$} \\
  P(A) = \bigl( m_{A}, \vec{0}\, \bigr) \qquad \mbox{in the rest frame of $A$}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

In fact, this output is completely unrelated to `gather` (and friends).

For alternatives to printing textual content in math mode, see [Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70632/5764).