# Latex equation problem by using MAC OS X Grapher

Tags: equations, mac

I have used MAC OS X Grapher to create this equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\mbox{C}skip\left( \; d\;  \right)\; =\; \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1+\mbox{C}m\cdot \left( Lm-d-1 \right), & if\; Rm\; =\; 1 \\ \frac{1+\mbox{C}m-Rm-\mbox{C}m\cdot Rm^{Lm-d-1}}{1-Rm}, & Otherwise \end{array}\right
\end{equation}
```

I should be something like this:
[image]

But when I've tried to add the code in my latex file it doesn't work, I got some errors.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 4):

`\left` and `\right` must be come in pairs, even if only one is needed. In this case the other delimiter is a period: `\left\{ ... \right.`.

But code and result are so ugly, it is much easier to rewrite them from scratch. Package `amsmath` provides the environment `cases`, which is used here. The used symbols are based on some wild guesses (e.g., `m` as index, ...):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  C_{\textnormal{skip}}(d) =
  \begin{cases}
    1 + C_m (L_m - d - 1), & \text{if $R_m=1$} \\
    \frac{1 + C_m - R_m - C_m R_m^{L_m - d -1}}{1 - R_m},
    & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The size of the fraction can be increased by `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`:

> [image: Result \dfrac]

The environment `dcases` of package `mathtools`, see [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253425/latex-equation-problem-by-using-mac-os-x-grapher/253427?noredirect=1#comment605289_253427) of Andrew Swann, also improves the vertical spacing:

> [image: Result dcases]

Comment: Yes you are right it was so ugly, because i just copied it from the Grapher tool directly.

Comment: Further simplification is to use `dcases*` from `mathtools`

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks, answer updated. It also improves the vertical spacing.

Comment: Please do not promote the use of `\text` for `C_{\text{skip}}` as soon a this is used in an italic context this will be wrong.

Comment: @daleif I have changed it to `\textnormal` the only reasonable alternative, see question "[Difference between various methods for producing text in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70632/16967)". Italic context with math is dead ugly.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek why not just `\textup`, shorter?

Comment: @daleif `\textup` is family sensitive. Then you would have typewriter in a `\ttfamily` context.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek but I think think you can make a case for both. If say a theorem design is in sans serif, it may look odd that a textual index comes up as non sans serif.

Comment: @daleif Then the same symbol changes its appearance, when used in a roman context again. IMHO the problem is such a design. Summary: a command that fits all needs does not exist.

Comment: Very efficient , thank you all ... I will update it ... many thanks again