# LaTeX: Larger spacing in equations by default

Tags: formatting, equations

I know that I can add spacings in equations using `\,`, `\:` and `\;`. However, by default, there is no spacing between two factors. Do I have to set every spacing manually using the above commands, or is there a way to increase the default spacing?

Thanks!

Edit:
In my case, an equation looks something like this:

[image]

... but should be more like this:

[image] .

(I guess, alternatively I could just add `\cdot`s between the characters to make it look nice, but the question still stands.)

Comment: Welcome, normally there is no spacing before factors. Can you how us your specific formula?

Comment: I added screenshots to the question. :)

Comment: Unrelated: `v_{\mathit{fall}}` or `v_{\mathrm{fall}}`

Comment: or, as I prefer,  `v_\textnormal{fall}` , see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70641/78282), for example

Comment: If you start changing the spacing between two objects of type `mathord`, you should be prepared to change the values of `\thinmuskip`, `\medmuskip`, and `\thickmuskip` as well. All in all, don't underestimate the complexity of such a project.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the math italic font *already* has large sidebearings so that adjacent letters look like a product of variables not a word. That is why `fall` is unreadable in the subscript shown and should be `\mathrm{fall}` or `\mathit{fall}` so that it uses a font without this feature.

The amount of space between these letters is considered part of the font design so the only way to change it in tex is to add spaces between each letter or to try a different font.

As shown below the spacing differences between math and text italic are mostly subtle but have a distinct effect on comprehension. But some letters, notably `f`, the spacing differences can be quite dramatic.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}



$6\pi r v_{fall} \eta$ painful!

$6\pi r v_{\mathit{fall}} \eta$ math italic main text and subscript

$6\pi r v_{\mathrm{fall}} \eta$ math italic main text roman subscript

$6\pi \mathit{r v_{\mathrm{fall}}} \eta$ text italic main text, roman subscript




\end{document}
```