# Fix ugly kerning in equation subscript

Tags: equations, kerning

I'm beautifying some HW solutions for the upcoming semester, and came across a kerning issue

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[C_{in} \ \ C_{out} \ \ C_{eff}\]

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

The "in" and "out" subscripts look fine, but "eff" seems very spread out.  Is there a quick fix?

Comment: That’s because the `eff` is interpreted as `e times f times f`, and the same goes for `in` and `out`. So you should either use the `\mathit` by @Sebastiano in the answer, or `\mathrm`, or `\text`, etc.

Comment: @RuixiZhang My thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In math-mode you should to use `\mathit{...}` (slanted} or `\mathbf{...}` (bold) or normal `\mathrm{...}` for any type of the text into math formula.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[C_{\mathit{in}} \ \ C_{\mathit{out}} \ \ C_{\mathit{eff}}\]
\[C_{\mathrm{in}} \ \ C_{\mathrm{out}} \ \ C_{\mathrm{eff}}\]
\[C_{\mathbf{in}} \ \ C_{\mathbf{out}} \ \ C_{\mathbf{eff}}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I would recommend \mathrm since eff is rather a label (short for effective) and not a variable (e times f times f). At least this is the convention that I am aware of.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I have forgotten \mathrm :-(. Now edit my answer. +1

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `\text` from the `amsmath` package. But there are different opinions about this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70632

Comment: Another alternative, `\operatorname`, is good if you ever need to set `in`, `out` or `eff` next to some other identifier. That formats and spaces it like the word log or sin.