# What is the correct way of writing the support of a function in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

So far i have been using $\text{supp} u$ but that is very cumbersome and probably wrong, do we have an equivalent of \lim for $\lim$?

Comment: You could use in math-mode `$\mathrm{supp} u$`. But your question is not very clear. Here there is an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448069/fix-ugly-kerning-in-equation-subscript/448070#448070.

Comment: `\text` is super wrong (too many people misuse `\text`), define `\supp` via `\DeclareMathOperator\supp{supp}` and use `\supp` or use `\newcommand\supp{\mathrm{supp}}` if you do not want it to behave as an operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator\supp{supp}

\begin{document}

  $\supp f(x)$

\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

Note that this requires the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. Actually, in the preamble of my papers I usually have quite a lot of these so instead I use code like:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for \forcsvlist

% mathematics operators
\newcommand{\DeclareMyOperator}[1]{%
  \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\csname #1\endcsname{#1}
}
\forcsvlist{\DeclareMyOperator}{%
   Ext, End, Hom, Ind, Mat,Res,
}
```

This defines `\Ext`, `\End`, ..., `\Res`. for me.

Answer (score 0):

The good think about `LaTex` is that it offers a lot of sophisticated commands, for instance, you can use:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent Some nice options (note that they also include super/sub scripts in them for instance \texttt{\\<one\_of\_the\_command>\_\{your\_subscript\}$^\wedge$\{your\_super\_script\}})
\begin{itemize}
    \item Supremum: $\sup$
\item   Maximum: $\max$
\item   Infimum: $\inf$
\item   Minimum: $\min$
\item   Limits: $\lim$
\item  Sum: $\sum$
\item $\ldots$
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

This is for instance, would give you:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Note that this is just `A` list. You can do much more than just listed here.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that there is no built-in macro for the support of a function, as it is commonly denoted by supp rather than sup.

Comment: @Circumscribe Noted it down ;)