# What does $\mbox$ do?

Tags: math-mode, boxes

The LaTeX wiki says it makes a box, but when I used it with `\mbox{Cos}` for example, it simply wrote "Cos" in the same way that writing Cos by itself would have done. What's the point of `\mbox`?

Comment: There are differences, try this:
\\(\mbox{Not italic and with spaces \\(some^{maths}\\)}Italic with spaces removed\\)

Comment: In LaTeX (and TeX) the word "box" means an unbreakable unit, whose contents are processed in text mode. `\mbox` is used when you want to keep some phrase from breaking at the end of a line. Occasionally it is used as a quick way to put a text-mode word or phrase inside a math display. There are also ways to store typeset material in a box (`\savebox`). Once stuff is saved in a box, it can be measured, reuse it later, etc. Boxes are all over LaTeX internal processing.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You don't really want to do that, because the spacing would be wrong.

The `\mbox` should typeset its argument in text mode even if in math mode; however it's wrong anyway. Operator names should be typeset in text mode, but with an upright font in any circumstance. With `\mbox` you don't ensure the correct spacing, nor that the font is right.

Look at the following example. In the pair of lines the first has `\mbox{Cos}`, the second one has `\Cos` properly defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cos}{Cos}

\begin{document}

Here we have a formula with the cosine $\mbox{Cos}0=1$.

Here we have a formula with the cosine $\Cos 0=1$.

\begin{thm}
Here we have a formula with the cosine $\mbox{Cos}0=1$.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
Here we have a formula with the cosine $\Cos 0=1$.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can notice that the spacing in the first line is slightly bad, but the result is dramatically wrong in the third line.

By the way, the cosine function has been named “cos” for centuries, until Mathematica came along and changed the conventions. I'll stay with the tradition, and LaTeX already provides `\cos` for that purpose.

---

It has been asked in comments to also deal with another usage of `\mbox` inside a math formula, say

```
$a+\mbox{\boldmath$\epsilon$}$
```

(actually moose is claiming to have found `${\mbox{\boldmath{$\epsilon$}}}$`, which I'm not really surprised of).

This is a very old, outdated and deprecated method for making a boldface math symbol. One has to remember that `\boldmath` is not legal *inside* a math formula: so with

```
$a+{\boldmath\epsilon}$
```

a warning about `Command \boldmath invalid in math mode` would be issued and `\boldmath` would be ignored. By switching to text mode within the `\mbox`, `\boldmath` becomes legal and produces the desired effect. Technical note: when `\mbox` appears in a formula, TeX suspends math mode, enters text mode, typesets the box and switches back to math mode at the end.

However, something like

```
$a_{\mbox{\boldmath$\epsilon$}}$
```

would have a bad output, because the symbol will not be in subscript size.

Since many years, a better method has been available: the instructions

```
\usepackage{bm}
```

allows one to say

```
$a+\bm{\epsilon}$
```

and

```
$a_{\bm{\epsilon}}$
```

getting a bold epsilon in the right size.

Comment: @Anonymous As I understand egreg, convention is to use 'cos' for the cosine function, while Mathematica uses 'Cos' (capital C). The former is available in LaTeX already, as `\cos`. That someone on Physics.SX probably didn't know better.

Comment: @Anonymous If you really want uppercase “Cos”, then add `\DeclareMathOperator{\Cos}{Cos}` with `\usepackage{amsmath}` as done in the example.

Comment: This is tangential to the actual question, but *Mathematica* has not changed the convention for cosine. In Wolfram language (aka InputForm, an ASCII-only 1-dimensional form), a cosine function is denoted "Cos[whatever]"; all functions in InputForm are capitalized and use square brackets when applied. When you display the expression (in 2-dimensional TraditionalForm, say), it's the same "cos(whatever)" as it always is. Analogously, you would not say LaTeX changed the convention for cosine to "\cos".